# I can't send body in data in body in post request of swift project in any api

Tags: swift

I can't send data in body in post request of swift project in any api. if I send the date to add in url than api will response.

```
let url: String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json" 
let para = ["key":googlekey, "components":"country:ids", "input":str, "types": "address"] 
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post,parameters: para, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
    .responseJSON { dataResponse in
```

Comment: Hi, it would be nice to see the code. This would help to understand the problem better.

Comment: let url: String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json"

 let para = ["key":googlekey, "components":"country:ids", "input":str, "types": "address"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post,parameters: para, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { dataResponse in

Comment: Please share your code as a part of the question. That way, it'll be better for us to understand your problem

Comment: I am using same code for our server to post api but server not responding but in old project server response proper (afnertworking and objective c used in old project)

Answer (score 2):

So, as I understood correctly you're using Google Maps API and the request you're trying to perform is a GET request which means that you need to specify request parameters in the URL itself, not the body. I think your request should look like this

```
    let googleKey = "your api key"
    let url: String = "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Apple&components=country:ids&input=\(str)&types=adress&key=\(googleKey)"
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I can't send data in body in post request of swift project in any api.

That is correct.

A `GET` request is, by definition, to request information from a web service (where parameters are supplied in the URL) and `POST` is to supply information to a web service (and the information to be stored is supplied in the body of the request). This search request to the Google Places API is simply requesting information from their web service, not storing anything, so it is appropriate that this is a `GET` request.

The [documentation for Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) is explicit that these parameters should just be included in the URL of the request:

> A Place Autocomplete request is an HTTP URL of the following form:
>
> ```
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/output?parameters
> ```
>
> where `output` may be either of the following values:
>
> - `json` (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
> - `xml` indicates output as XML
>
> ...

Bottom line, I’d suggest you let Alamofire build this `GET` request, adding the parameters to the URL for you (doing all of the percent escaping for you):

```
Alamofire.request(url, parameters: para)   // or, in Alamofire 5, `AF.request(...)`
    .responseJSON { response in
        ...
}
```

The `method` defaults to `.get` and the `encoding` to `URLEncoding.default`, so these can be omitted to reduce syntactic noise.

---

By the way, if you’re interested in the difference between `GET` and `POST` (which drives the rationale used by web service API developers), see the discussion of “method” in HTTP specifications, e.g. [GET](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) vs [POST](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5).